# Storing DateTime property instead of byte array in SQL table using Code-First MVC5 EF6

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

When I try to initialize my database using EF6 in MVC5 I get the error: **The property 'Timestamp' is not a Byte array. IsRowVersion can only be configured for Byte array properties.** Is there a way I can override the IsRowVersion using FluentAPI or is there another method to store DateTime using MVC5 EF6 or is this simply the result of using the Timestamp data annotation? I prefer to store as DateTime instead of byte array. Just for visualization Model looks like this:

```
    public class UserProfile : IdentityUser
    {

        //ctor
        public UserProfile()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int pic = rnd.Next(1, 6); 

            DateJoined = DateTime.Now;
            UserLevel = 4;
            ImageUrl = "/Content/Avatars/Samples/sample" + pic + ".jpg"; // or append &#46;jpg which == .jpg
        }

        public UserProfile(string name, string url)
        {
            UserName = name;
            DateJoined = DateTime.Now;
            UserLevel = 4;
            ImageUrl = url;
            Email = "your@email.com";
        }

        public UserProfile(string name, string url, string email)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int pic = rnd.Next(1, 6);
            UserName = name;
            DateJoined = DateTime.Now;
            UserLevel = 4;
            ImageUrl = "/Content/Avatars/sample" + pic + ".jpg"; // or append &#46;jpg which == .jpg
            Email = email;
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="*Username is required."), RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L} \p{Nd}_]+$")]
         [MinLengthAttribute(5, ErrorMessage="Not enough characters! UserName must be at least 5 chars."), MaxLengthAttribute(30,ErrorMessage="Too many characters in UserName!")]
        public override string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="*Email is required."), EmailAddress, RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false),Required]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0}")] //{0:d} or {0:D}
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Timestamp, ScaffoldColumn(false)] //<--Problem 
        public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 6), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int UserLevel { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int? TotalRepPoints { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public virtual IDictionary<int, int> TotalPointsByCat { get; set; }
        // int = CategoryId, int = UserRank
        public virtual IDictionary<int, int> Rankings { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    }
```

When I use NuGet Console:

```
 PM> Enable-Migrations -Force
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Timestamp' is not a Byte array. IsRowVersion can only be configured for Byte array properties.
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration.IsRowVersion()
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TimestampAttributeConvention.Apply(ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration configuration, TimestampAttribute attribute)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
...
    The property 'Timestamp' is not a Byte array. IsRowVersion can only be configured for Byte array properties.
    PM>
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

When storing properties using data annotation  `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]`
with `DateTime?` class you will get datetime type field in SQL.

When storing properties using data annotation `[Timestamp]`
with `byte[]` you will get timestamp type field in SQL.

[image]

Comment: by general even in SQL timestamp is stored as binnary therefore the EF will map it to Byte array

Comment: This same code works fine using MVC 4 and when I look at the column in SQL Server Management Studio it in fact says it is of type datetime when using MVC4 <. So I guess I am wondering why the change and is the only way to resolve this issue is to create a helper that convert into byte array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are storing date time why you need timestamp it totally different datatypes

Comment: Did not realize that this is what maps EF to SQL byte array-to-timestamp. So this code worked and it shouldn't have in the past. [Timestamp] is in fact mapping byte array in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Microsoft documentation on `timestamp` (AKA `rowversion`)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) (emphasis added):

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The rowversion data type **is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.** To record a date or time, use a datetime2 data type.

So this data type, despite its old name, has essentially nothing to do with actual datetime values as we generally think of them.

Pick another column type, like datetime.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer since I would have never thought to research this and yet I find this information very resourceful. So I guess now I am wondering why this data type ceases to still exist? Since it is incremental is having a column type of rowversion used for indexing or maybe unique identifier nowadays? 8 bytes == big int (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) - (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) seems a bit of overkill to use for indexing or anything except maybe a unique identifier.

Comment: @yardpenalty the idea behind the `rowversion` type is it runs automatically every time the record is touched. You don't have to rely on app developers to remember to correctly revise the value every time they touch that record; it "just works".

Comment: @REX M I found this excellent article on **rowversion** at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/670510/Rowversion-Version-Stamping-A-Row which also states that Microsoft has deprecated timestamp. This is actually a really useful data type as it can be used for change tracking. Time to actually use rowversion. :-)

Comment: @yardpenalty sounds good! Feel free to mark this answer correct if the question is settled for you.

Comment: @yardpenalty FYI, that's done by clicking the big ✓ mark next to the answer, below the voting buttons.

Comment: @Rex I am sorry I figured that by being the askee and upvoting that would do the trick. Thanks for the info.